# migrate IndexedDB data to an array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, data-migration, dexie

I am relatively new to web development and currently trying to work out an "offline" Application with vue.js and dexie.js.
Dexie.js allows easier access on modern browsers Indexed Database.

Nontheless I believe my problem is more on the basic javascript side.

I got this basic DB("enhanced" with Dexie):

```
var db = new Dexie("appDatabase");
db.version(1).stores({
   tasks: '++id,name, agi, str, vit, int',
   player: 'id, name, agi, str, vit, int',
});
```

(yes, only one player is allowed)

..and editing and adding data into the indexedDB works perfectly fine... Now I am trying to transfer data from the IndexedDB to an array for easier visuals within Vue.js
(I chose noneOf because I don't mind the player to leave the name empty)

```
        transferDBtoArray() {
            db.tasks.where('name').noneOf().toArray(function(result) {
                for(var i= 0; i< result.length; i++) {
                    app.tasks[i].id = result[i].id;
                    app.tasks[i].name = result[i].name;
                    app.tasks[i].str = result[i].str;
                    app.tasks[i].int = result[i].int;
                    app.tasks[i].vit = result[i].vit;
                    app.tasks[i].agi = result[i].agi;
                    
                }
            });
```

when this is my array structure within the vue app:

```
        tasks : [
            {id: 0, name:"", str: 0, agi: 0, int: 0, vit: 0}
        ],
```

Sadly, it won't work as intended :

```
Unhandled rejection: TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
```

I do know that accessing data from the DB works fine:

```
        test() {
            db.tasks.where('name').noneOf().toArray(function(result) {
                for(var i= 0; i< result.length; i++) {
                    console.log( result[i].name);
                    console.log( result[i].agi);
                    console.log( result[i].str);
                    console.log( result[i].int);
                    console.log( result[i].vit);
                }
            });
        },
```

```
js.js:136 hüpfen
js.js:137 10
js.js:138 2
js.js:139 5
js.js:140 10
js.js:136 instagrammen
js.js:137 10
js.js:138 10
js.js:139 10
js.js:140 10
js.js:136 lollen
js.js:137 1
js.js:138 1
js.js:139 1
js.js:140 1
js.js:136 rennen
js.js:137 5
js.js:138 3
js.js:139 2
js.js:140
```

I am guessing that my mistake is within the structuring of the array but I am not sure..

Any help would be really appreciated and kind regards

Richard

Comment: I guess `app.tasks[i]` is undefined, not `result[i]`, please check that or include the code of `app.tasks`

Comment: app.tasks[i] is undefined by design(hence the empty strings and 0 in tasks[]) and should only be defined when migrating data from the indexed database..unless I am not mistaken and this is impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `app.tasks[i]` to an empty object at the beginning of each assignment in the loop:

```
    transferDBtoArray() {
        db.tasks.where('name').noneOf().toArray(function(result) {
            for(var i= 0; i< result.length; i++) {
                app.tasks[i] = {};
                app.tasks[i].id = result[i].id;
                app.tasks[i].name = result[i].name;
                app.tasks[i].str = result[i].str;
                app.tasks[i].int = result[i].int;
                app.tasks[i].vit = result[i].vit;
                app.tasks[i].agi = result[i].agi;
                
            }
        });
```

Or better yet:

```
transferDBtoArray() {
  db.tasks.where('name').noneOf().toArray(results => results.map(result => ({          
        id: result.id,
        name: result.name,
        str: result.str,
        int: result.int,
        vit: result.vit,
        agi: result.agi,
  })));
```

Comment: Your first solution worked just fine. May I ask ...why?  or rather.. Why do I need to set it to an empty object when app.tasks[i] should be empty from be beginning?

Comment: Because there is a difference between an empty object and undefined. Think of the empty object as being a blank piece of paper you can write on, whereas undefined is like no paper at all. It's just a javascript rule: you must assign some object before you can assign values to fields. By the way, while the first example works, the second would be considered much 'nicer' by most js programmers. Please mark as answer/upvote if it helped! Cheers.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the detailed answer. It helped me a lot!